# Convert categories to columns in dataframe python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, transpose

I have a dataframe which contains two columns. One column contains different categories and other contains values.

```
import pandas as pd

data={"category":["Topic1","Topic2","Topic3","Topic2","Topic1","Topic3"], "value":["hello","hey","hi","name","valuess","python"]}

df=pd.DataFrame(data=data)
```

I want different categories into column as given below.

Current Input:

```
category    value
  Topic1    hello
  Topic2      hey
  Topic3       hi
  Topic2     name
  Topic1  valuess
  Topic3   python
```

Desired Output:

```
Topic1  Topic2 Topic3
hello    hey    hi
valuess name    python
```

I tried using transposing the dataframe but not getting the expected result.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [`pandas.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.concat.html) along `axis=1`. This will also work for mismatched lengths.

```
grouper = df.groupby('category')
df = pd.concat([pd.Series(v['value'].tolist(), name=k) for k, v in grouper], axis=1)

print(df)

    Topic1 Topic2  Topic3
0    hello    hey      hi
1  valuess   name  python
```

Comment: Thanks!! This solution is efficient.

Answer (score 3):

```
s = df.groupby('category')['value'].apply(list)
s.apply(pd.Series).T

category   Topic1 Topic2  Topic3
0           hello    hey      hi
1         valuess   name  python
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `pivot` and `cumcount`(For the help key creation)

```
df.assign(key=df.groupby('category').cumcount()).pivot('key','category','value')
Out[381]: 
category   Topic1 Topic2  Topic3
key                             
0           hello    hey      hi
1         valuess   name  python
```